# What is the recommended way to organize platform specific code in C++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

If I want to write my C++ application for multiple platforms, e.g. Windows and Linux, what is the recommended way of writing the platform code? What pattern, class hierarchy etc. exists to accomplish this task? How should I organize my code, header and source files?

Comment: are you asking about GUI, FS... ? design patterns? libraries? please clarify

Comment: Yes, header and source files is a good way to organize your code.

Comment: Someone edited my title. It should read "dependant code"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't get your question completely, but generally you should separate your platform dependent code from platform independent one. for example you may have a folder `platform` and inside it a folder for each platform that supported by you, then you may have `win32/mutex.hpp`, `linux/mutex.hpp`, `mac/mutex.hpp` and in each of them you may add implementation of mutex for that platform. Then all you need is a single selector header that based on platform select correct file and include it. For example `platform/mutex.hpp` that include any of specified files in correct platform.

But beside that, take a look at `boost` it implement many platform dependent code in a platform independent manner, you can learn from it and you may see implementation of your platform dependent code there!!

Comment: .. why would you re-invent the wheel?

Comment: It is always possible that you have a code that need to implemented for different platforms! but many libraries like `boost` or `poco` actually do many part of it in a very good manner

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I read this as just an example.

Comment: How do you link then? Do you provide the functions' definitions in the header files?

Comment: @GuillemVS there is 2 ways:
- First if all implementation is header only, I already said the correct way in my answer how to include the correct file (using `platform/mutex.hpp`). this way require previous platform selection based on predefined MACROs
- But if you have some implementation code in `.cpp` file, then you must include them in your build script and merge them with your original code.

For more information see implementation of libraries like `boost` or `poco`

Answer (score 5):

1. Stick to standards defined by C++ ISO specifications.
2. Use PLATFORM independent libraries (like Boost and Qt and Fltk)
3. Make sure you don't use COMPILER specific extensions, or atleast stick to 1 SINGLE compiler(recommended: G++ which is cross platform)

   Follow these first. Patterns are but means of organising code. Standard patterns allowed by a language theoretically remain the same across all platforms, so that shouldn't be a part of the problem
4. Use #ifdef MACROS to code platform specific path to files, platform specific libraries for networking etc.

More you remain platform independent, more you will have to rely on third party toolkits.

Organization:

```
FOLDERS: program
         |_plaf
         |_headers
         |_source
         |_makescripts

plaf
|_win32 //contains windows specific wrapper functions in header files
|_unix  //contains unix specific wrapper functions in header files

headers: //contains platform independent headers
lib: //contains platform independent static libraries
sources: //contains .h and .cxx(or .cc or .cpp) files. ONE file per class with main function in main.cxx
```